# Bash script break nested loop with "break [n]" failed

Tags: bash, infinite-loop, break

Here is my code:

```
while [[ "$counter" -gt 0 ]];
do
  startNewTest
  echo -e "\n" | ./myscript.sh send

  while :
  do
    sleep 30
    echo -e "\n Reading status... \n"
    ./myscript.sh status | \
    while read i
    do
      if echo $i | grep -q "$KEYWORD"
      then
        echo -e "\n Starting a new round of test... \n"
        break 2
      fi
    done
  done
  let counter=counter-1
done
```

When the if condition is met, the "break 2" line should break 2 layers of loop, right? However, when i ran the script, it only break the inner-most loop, and stuck inside the infinite "while :" loop. Where did i make the mistake?
I also tried "break 3", didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test this with your `myscript.sh` ?
It seems you are breaking out of a subprocess after the pipe sign.
Getting the output in the while-loop without a subprocess might help:

```
while [[ "$counter" -gt 0 ]];
do
  startNewTest
  echo -e "\n" | ./myscript.sh send

  while :
  do
    sleep 30
    echo -e "\n Reading status... \n"

    while read i
    do
      if echo $i | grep -q "$KEYWORD"
      then
        echo -e "\n Starting a new round of test... \n"
        break 2
      fi
    done < <(./myscript.sh status)

  done
  let counter=counter-1
done
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! Can you explain this line "done < <(./myscript.sh status)" cause i'm not familiar with the syntax here. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @user3242431 It's [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, i'll go take a look at it.